# How to whitelist IPs for Windows Firewall with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-firewall

Is doing New-NetFirewallRule for each IP address I want to Allow my only option with Windows Firewall and PowerShell?  The docs say that -RemoteAddress can only be a single IP address, an address range, a subnet or a keyword (e.g. Any), but not a list.  Suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put each IP into an array and then loop the firewall whitelist command.

```
$IParray = @('192.168.1.4','8.8.8.8','192.168.1.43','192.168.1.55')

foreach($ip in $IParray)
{
     New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow $ip" -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -RemoteAddress $ip
}
```

This will create a single rule for each IP in the list and name each rule "Allow X.X.X.X" substituting that for the current IP in the list.